# Al intentar activar Unicorn, aparece "cannot import name Deque" y luego "el término 'uvicorn' no se reconoce como nombre de un cmdlet, función(...)"

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, fastapi

Estoy creando mi primera API en Python, ya creé el entorno virtual y en el, instalé FastAPI y Uvicorn. Cuando ejecuto el código para activar el Uvicorn, me sale el error de la primera línea: `cannot import name Deque` y luego me sale el código de error en rojo, y eso ya no lo entiendo por qué sale. ¿Lo estoy usando de manera correcta?, ¿qué estoy haciendo mal?
El código es muy sencillo, no creo que sea lo que esté mal:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
    
app = FastAPI()
    
@app.get("/")
def inicio():
    return "Hola Mundo"
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Windows no reconoce el comando `uvicorn`. Tenes [2 soluciones](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63635664/3791844). Fijate cual te sirve y recordá que podes responder a tu propia pregunta. Saludos!

Comment: Hola andresjnc, bienvenido, si tu versión de Python es anterior a la 3.6, no te funcionará, deberás actualizarla.

Comment: @Marcos Muchas gracias por tu respuesta! Me sirvió muchísimo!

Comment: @MarcePuente Muchas gracias por tu respuesta! Ahí actualicé el Python y me funcionó!

Comment: @andresjnc, que bueno que lo pudiste solucionar! Sería genial si pudieras crear una respuesta con los pasos que realizaste. Saludos

Comment: @Marcos cómo puedo hacer eso? Soy bastante nuevo en esta comunidad.

Comment: @andresjnc, solo tenes que hacer clic en el botón que dice "Responde tu propia pregunta" ubicado debajo de este comentario. En mi caso [se ve así](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1VD4.png)

Comment: @Marcos genial, ahí lo pruebo, gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Así está resuelto en el link que me pasó Marcos, y de esta forma me ayudó muchísimo.

1. Primero, hay que ir hacia la consola e instalar uvicorn:
   `pip install uvicorn`
   Al instalarlo, saldrá la ruta donde fue instalado, en mi caso fue `appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages`.
2. Después, nos dirigimos hacia la ruta que obtuvimos. Ahí, hay que copiar las carpetas `uvicorn` y `uvicorn-X.XX.Xdist-info` (en las X debería encontrarse la versión de uvicorn)
3. Pegar las 2 carpetas en donde tengan instalado Python, en la carpta `Scripts`
4. Vayan a esta ruta `users/AppData/roaming/Python/Python36/Scripts` y copien `uvicorn.exe`
5. Pegan el archivo donde pegaron las dos carpetas anteriormente.
   Y listo, solo queda que al ejecutar el código en la terminal ingresen `uvicorn nombre_del_archivo:app --reload`

Comment: +1 por responder a tu pregunta detalladamente, como corresponde :) No olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta.

Comment: @padaleiana gracias por el consejo y por el voto positivo!